# You've got to go right down the line, with multiple bites in order to make that all back

Tags: phrase-usage

I encountered an unfamiliar phrase on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdYiPSl0xpo):

> 2:01 you've got to **go right down the line**, with multiple bites in order to make that all back.

I guess this sentence is talking about how movie studios regain their investments.

I check the highlighted phrase in my dictionary, but I couldn't find the meaning.
Is this kind of a metaphor?

Comment: See this: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+the+line. It basically means that you have to do it all and it has the suggestion of being mechanical, like you checking every box. Of course, the person who is saying this is totally wrong - movie studios murder their franchises by overpopularizing them.

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice that **down the line** alone has a meaning.